# How to use AWS S3 in WinForm project - CSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm been reading multiples articles about the usage of the AWS S3 in Visual Studio. But all of those are focused on Web implementation.

Has anyone had the need to implement AWS S3 in WinForms - C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented a class in C# that interact basically with AWS S3 without having too much configuration.

** I'm using the MS Framework 4.5 **

First of all, remember to use the NuGet Package and install the AWS references (In VS >> Menu >> Tools >> NuGet Package Manager >> Manage NuGet Package Manager for Solution):

- AWSSDK - Amazon Simple Storage Service
- AWSSDK - Core Runtime

...implemented this class, for my need I only required the access key, secret key, region and the bucket (Exists more methods, but I only required copy, read and delete).

Note: It's not required additional configuration in the app.config file or install/create a profile in the USER folder...

```
public class clsAwsS3
{
    string accessKey { get; set; }
    string secretKey { get; set; }
    string bucket { get; set; }
    RegionEndpoint region { get; set; }
    IAmazonS3 client;

    public clsAwsS3(string strBucket, string strAccessKey, string strSecretKey, RegionEndpoint region)
    {
        this.bucket = strBucket;
        this.accessKey = strAccessKey;
        this.secretKey = strSecretKey;
        this.region = region;
        login();
    }

    private void login()
    {
        client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, region);
    }

    public List<string> getItems(string strPrefix = "")
    {
        List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
        ListObjectsV2Request listRequest;

        if (strPrefix == "")
            listRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucket
            };
        else
            listRequest = new ListObjectsV2Request
            {
                BucketName = bucket,
                Prefix = strPrefix
            };

        ListObjectsV2Response listResponse;

        do
        {
            listResponse = client.ListObjectsV2(listRequest);

            foreach (S3Object awsObject in listResponse.S3Objects)
                lstResult.Add(awsObject.Key);

            listRequest.ContinuationToken = listResponse.NextContinuationToken;
        } while (listResponse.IsTruncated);

        return lstResult;
    }

    public string downloadItem(string strItemKey, string strDestination)
    {
        GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucket,
            Key = strItemKey
        };

        using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request))
        {
            response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(strDestination);
        }

        return strDestination;
    }

    public void copyItem(string strItemKeySource, string strItemKeyDestination)
    {
        CopyObjectRequest copyRequest = new CopyObjectRequest
        {
            SourceBucket = bucket,
            SourceKey = strItemKeySource,
            DestinationBucket = bucket,
            DestinationKey = strItemKeyDestination
        };

        CopyObjectResponse copyResponse = client.CopyObject(copyRequest);

        if (copyResponse.HttpStatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            throw new Exception("Item has an error");
    }

    public void deleteItem(string strItemKey)
    {
        DeleteObjectRequest deleteObject = new DeleteObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = bucket,
            Key = strItemKey
        };

        DeleteObjectResponse deleteResponse = client.DeleteObject(deleteObject);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps to someone else.